# Best Practices for Primary Key in DocumentDB

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a web site with azure DocumentDB. I need to create unique and short primary key.

Since there isn't available auto increment in documentDB is there any good way to handle this problem.

I expect the answer with best practice advices. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a document class whose primary key is named as PrimaryKey

```
public class Document<T> : BaseDocument, IDocument<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public virtual T PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    }
```

Since the document db primary key is **id** (lower case mandatory), You can replace the id with JSONProperty of **Newtonsoft.Json**, which will automatically get serialized with the value of PrimaryKey in the name of id.

Comment: I'd add that `PrimaryKey` must be of type `string`. Otherwise you get "Ensure to provide a unique non-empty string less than '255' characters" exception when creating a document.

Comment: I use guid as my primary key and it works seamless in MS-Doc db in azure and also in local.

Answer (score 4):

The most common practice I've seen is to simply use a GUID assigned when you create the new document to be added/inserted. You can also specify the [Indexing Policy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/). This can help support situations where you need to find a document based on other properties within those documents.

Creating a custom, composite key is also useful if you usually know exactly which document you want to retrieve. In this case its up to the individual application to determine the best way to create the composite value.

Answer (score -1):

If you need incremental, numerical and unique keys, you can use the Javascript date `new Date().getTime()` in milliseconds as the unique identifier for each document. The advantage to this is that, if you need to search documents by range, you can configure this property as a range index and do efficient ranges searches. Depending on your application, chances that 2 documents will be created in the same millisecond are pretty slim.

Comment: As a heads up for anyone reading these comments for advice, I would seriously advise against designing race conditions like the above into your application, a unique identifier should be absolutely unique, what happens in the above when that "slim chance" is hit... your referential integrity is gone and you'll probably loose data.. (i.e. one won't get saved)....

Comment: @dreadeddev: in the context of documentDb, your observation is not entirely accurate. DocumentDB will automatically assign a unique ID to every document within a collection. This ID is guaranteed to be unique. So, in case of such a race condition, the documents will still be saved in the DB.  But if your app is so massive that saving new documents within a collection can indeed happen within the same millisecond, and this property needs to be incrementally unique, then yes, you'll have to devise a different algorithm to solve that problem.

Comment: Indeed the asker does.... his question was regarding creation of Id's himself.... not the auto assigned one!